# Python psycopg2

Tags: python, for-loop, psycopg2

I am trying to execute a terminal command and send the output to a table in  postgress Database:

```
res = subprocess.Popen('bgpq3 -4 AS-YAHOO-JP-2 -m 24 -l Google', shell=True,
                       universal_newlines=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

for line in res.split('\n')[1:]:
   po=line.split()
   c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "AS" ("prefix" text)')
   c.execute('INSERT INTO AS ("prefix") VALUES (%s)',(po))
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oefenen.py", line 30, in <module>
    c.execute('INSERT INTO AS ("prefix") VALUES (%s)',(po))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

can anyone help me with this?

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO AS ("prefix") VALUES (%s)'[po])
```

with this command the ouput in DB wil be in my table but i dont want ({},) in my table :

```
{ip,prefix-list,Google,permit,14.137.224.0/19}
```

Comment: You have to add a comma to make it a tuple: `... ,(po,)`

Comment: i still get the same output {ip,prefix-list,Google,permit,14.137.224.0/19}